# Whats wrong with my PHP scraper script?

Tags: php, curl, scraper

so here's my PHP script:

```
<?php

function scrape(){

$f=fopen("list.txt","r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

    while (!feof($f))
{
        $site=stream_get_line($f,4096,"\n");
        $url="www.majesticseo.com/reports/site-explorer/summary/".$site."?IndexDataSource=F";


            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);



        $regex = '~External Backlinks\s*</p>\s*<p style="font-size: 150%;">\s*<b>(.+?)</b>~';

        $result=preg_match($regex,$data,$match);


        $link_count=$match[1];
        echo($site." ".$link_count);
        echo("</br>"); }

}

$ch=curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.majesticseo.com/account/login');

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'EmailAddress=myemail@email.com&Password=mypassword123');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$store=curl_exec($ch);

scrape();

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

The problem with it is that the scrape() function and the login part work when tested separately, however, when I want to scrape() inside the login curl session, it seems to scrape without being logged in. I know this because the limit for scraping sites without login has been reached, and it doesnt return any data.

Why does this happen? How can I make my script scrape the data WHILE being logged in?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! I changed the code so that I only have 1 CURL init. I didn't realise I was actually starting 2 sessions!